# How bad is unprivileged_userns_clone option for systems security?

Tags: google-chrome, security, debian

We're having some issues running our Electron-based app on Debian 10 as it uses Chrome runtime, Chrome requires its sandbox to run and, on defaults, Chrome sandbox won't run on Debian.

Surely, basic solution would be to run without sandbox on Debian, but that option has massive security risks that I'm not comfortable with.

There are other options. The one described in Electron docs and oh so many tutorials is enabling kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone flag:

```
echo kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
```

Supposedly that how it works on other desktop distributions, like Ubuntu. Yet there still are security risks that I just don't fully understand. So far I've found several relevant discussions:

- https://lwn.net/Articles/673597/
- https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=54591

But I'm failing to grasp what exactly is the tradeoff here. How does enabling unprivileged_userns_clone affect security? What are these risks exactly? Are there better options to run Chrome sandbox on Debian securely (as we are stuck with it)?

Comment: Related https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209529/what-does-enabling-kernel-unprivileged-userns-clone-do

Comment: @GAD3R thanks, didn't find it for some reason. Now I'm even more confused.